# Can someone help me convert an codepen into an react sandbox fiddle?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I created an codepen with react code and I'm importing its libraries trough CDN.
Now I want to implement this code (working) into my react project.
But first It could be handy to put all code into a react sandbox so I can make changes before deploying to my code.

I tried to copy paste all code into a sandbox and add all libraries `(react, react-dnd, reactdndhtml5backend, react-dom)`, but it still gives me a lot of errors.
Also the files in my own project are `.tsx` and not `.js`.

My current codepen is found here: https://codepen.io/darkinfore/pen/daJxyP
This works, but just not when I implement this into a react sandbox.
I also tried to implement this into a react sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/w01l077w1w
But as you can see it gives me some strange errors.

Can someone help me with converting this codepen into a react sandbox without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over your codesandbox and then [forked it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o573pj4w7z). Actually, the only error encountered had to do with `ReactDnD` not being defined (such that `DropTarget` could not be found). This was due to your import statement near the top of `index.js`:

```
import ReactDnD from "react-dnd";
```

Because of the way the `react-dnd` package is designed, this way of importing will not work for you. The package has multiple exports (for example, `DragDropContext` and `DropTarget`) rather than a single, default export. You need to take all of these exports and import them together into a single named import, called `ReactDnD`. So, what you need to do is:

```
import * as ReactDnD from "react-dnd";
```

I did this in the [forked codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o573pj4w7z), and this got you past the `TypeError` and then displayed your table.

---

Helpful information:

- [Different ways to use `import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [Exported modules from react-dnd package](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/packages/react-dnd/src/index.ts)